# How should I remove the title from each slide in beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles

I am preparing for a presentation using the beamer. Here is the code  in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
\usebeamerfont{footline}%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
\hspace{1em}%
\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\title{\texttt{\LARGE My Mathematical journey}  }
\institute{Institute of Mathematical Studies} 
\author{Tom Scott}
\date{November 2021}
```

I did not write the above code but I adopted it from the examples given in the LaTeX editor and I understand it to some extent. But
[image: Slide]

I am not able to get rid of the title and author name which comes on every page in the right corner. So what should I add/modify in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an empty optional argument to `\author` and `\title` as in `\author[]{Tom Scott}` should get you closer to the expected output:

| Output of the original code | output of the modified code |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

---

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
\usebeamerfont{footline}%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
\hspace{1em}%
\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\title[]{\texttt{\LARGE My Mathematical journey}}
\institute{Institute of Mathematical Studies} 
\author[]{Tom Scott}
\date{November 2021}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{section}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title}
contents
\end{frame}

\section{another section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title}
contents
\end{frame}

\section{last section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title}
contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```